# Toggle between two monitors using batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, toggle, monitor, multiple-monitors

I'm trying to change between my first monitor and both monitors on at the same time. When I use  displayswitch.exe /internal or  displayswitch.exe /extend on cmd they always work, however I cannot made this code to work inside the batch file. Can someone help me? Thx

```
@echo off

REM Check current display mode
powershell -command "(Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\wmi -Class WmiMonitorConnectionParams).Active"

REM Check if current mode is "Extend" or "Internal"
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" (
    REM Current mode is "Extend", switch to "Internal"
    echo Switching to Internal display mode...
    displayswitch.exe /internal
) else (
    REM Current mode is "Internal", switch to "Extend"
    echo Switching to Extend display mode...
    displayswitch.exe /extend
)

echo Display mode switched successfully.
pause
```

Comment: The first thing I'd ask is that you perform a couple of tests, (under different modes), using just **1.** ```@%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command "(Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\wmi -Class WmiMonitorConnectionParams).Active"``` and **2.** ```@Echo %ErrorLevel%& Pause```. My best guess, regardless of the current mode, is that the ErrorLevel will always be `0`, as it is returning that the `powershell.exe` was run successfully, not what the result of the `-Command` was.